# Apache Camel PAHO MQTT component does not receive messages after disconnecting

Tags: apache-camel, mqtt, paho, spring-camel

I saw this same issue here, but don't understand how to fix this issue based on the response.

[Camel PAHO routes not receiving offline messages while connecting back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248757/camel-paho-routes-not-receiving-offline-messages-while-connecting-back)

Is receiving offline messages possible at the paho endpoint and if so how?  Would this require modifying the source code?

I verified I receive offline messages using mosquitto_sub from the command line.

Here's my endpoint configuration:

`<from uri="paho:JUNK?brokerUrl=tcp://localhost:1883?cleanSession=false&amp;qos=2&amp;clientId=camel_test" />`

Some more details.  It appears that when disconnecting the camel client, the client is unsubscribing first which is preventing the client from receiving the offline messages when it reconnects.

```
Sep 21 06:33:40 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684420: camel_test JUNK
Sep 21 06:33:40 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684420: Sending UNSUBACK to camel_test
Sep 21 06:33:40 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684420: Received DISCONNECT from camel_test
Sep 21 06:33:40 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684420: Client camel_test disconnected.
```

The mosquitto_sub command line client is not unsubscribing on disconnects and is therefore able to receive the offline messages on reconnect.

```
Sep 21 06:33:21 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684400: Client ns_consumer disconnected.
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: New client connected from ::1 as ns_consumer (p2, c0, k60).
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: Sending CONNACK to ns_consumer (1, 0)
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: Sending PUBLISH to ns_consumer (d0, q2, r0, m26, 'JUNK', ... (189 bytes))
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: Received SUBSCRIBE from ns_consumer
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: ns_consumer 2 JUNK
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: Sending SUBACK to ns_consumer
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: Sending PUBLISH to ns_consumer (d0, q2, r1, m27, 'JUNK', ... (189 bytes))
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: Received PUBREC from ns_consumer (Mid: 26)
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: Sending PUBREL to ns_consumer (m26)
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: Received PUBREC from ns_consumer (Mid: 27)
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: Sending PUBREL to ns_consumer (m27)
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: Received PUBCOMP from ns_consumer (Mid: 26, RC:0)
Sep 21 06:42:23 me mosquitto.mosquitto[1290]: 1600684943: Received PUBCOMP from ns_consumer (Mid: 27, RC:0)
```

Comment: What version of Camel are you using?

Comment: I’m using Version 3.4.3. Wondering if this could be due to the client unsubscribing first on disconnects?  Is there a updated version that addresses this?

Comment: Verified the same unsubscribe functionality occurs in camel 3.5.0

Comment: Nevermind...Figured out the issue.  Incorrect url syntax so cleanSession was never being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was incorrect syntax in the endpoint configuration so cleanSession was never getting set via the paramter and defaulting to true.

`<from uri="paho:JUNK?brokerUrl=tcp://localhost:1883?cleanSession=false&amp;qos=2&amp;clientId=camel_test" />`

should be

`<from uri="paho:JUNK?brokerUrl=tcp://localhost:1883&amp;cleanSession=false&amp;qos=2&amp;clientId=camel_test" />`